# Git: Pull and Merge Questions

Tags: git, merge, git-submodules, pull

I'm following Git tutorials but I'm still not very clear about the Pull command and the effects on the remote and local repositories.

My two questions are the following:

Q1:
Let's say I have a project with submodules 1 2 and 3, the local and remote repos are up to date. Now, a teammate changes submodule 3 on the remote repo.
So now, the remote will be ahead by one commit.

- If I decide to go into my local project and Pull.
  Will submodule 3 on my local repo be updated with the information that is on the repo?
  In other words, will it overwrite whatever is on my local repo with that information?

Q2:

- If submodule 3, let's say has five files, and is is up to date with my local repo.
  And teammate **deletes** two files in the remote, leaving only three files on the remote repository.

If I then go into my local repo and Pull, will extra files on local be deleted so that it is up to date with what's on the remote, leaving a total of just three files?

Thanks

Comment: These questions seem like they could be answered by some simple experimentation. It sounds like you haven't actually tried the things you're asking about

Comment: The general effect of `git pull` is to import any changes from the remote into your local repo (in your current branch), so the answer to both your questions is yes.  I'm curious what _else_ you thought it would do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will it overwrite whatever is on my local repo with that information?

It will *update* but not necessarily *overwrite* the content in your submodule 3 directory. If you have no local modifications, yes then `git pull` will update all files updated remotely. If you should have any files modified you will get a conflict (can be mitigated with `git pull origin --rebase`). In other words there is nothing special with this submodule repository, `git pull` behaves the same as everywhere.

Where there is a difference though is that after you do a pull inside the submodule it will be marked as updated and dirty in the parent repository **but it will not make any changes to the version it is linked to**. To do that you need to explicitly from the parent repo do `git add submodule3dir; git commit -m "Updated submodule 3 to latest version"`.

In other words git pull inside a submodule will update your *worktree*, but it will not update your index and it will not create a corresponding commit. You need to explicitly run `add` and `commit` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and Yes.
You will have have the latest update even if that includes some file deletion..
For `Git`, that’s one of the possible “modifications” that could be applied to a file, and that `Git` could track.